# What's best way to clone a GIT project into a Web application with existing and non-GIT files?

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, bitbucket

*Want to cut to the chase?* Jump down to **QUESTIONS** below. Cheers.

## BACKGROUND

- I am changing my web development workflow to include GIT for version
  control. GIT is new to me, although I have a technical background, so
  it's not a complete mystery. :-)
- I have a GIT repository on Bitbucket (*BB*), which I use as the central project container.
- I use my local web server (on Mac OS X) for development.
  That's my *dev* server.
- Once tested locally, I push changes from my *dev* server to Bitbucket.
- I have two remote servers. One is a staging server, the other is the production/live server.
- I've learnt (sufficiently, for now) how to manage the files between *dev* and Bitbucket. I have everything set up to run over password-less SSH (using rsa keys).

## THE ISSUE

I am not sure what the proper or recommended way is to manage the workflow between *BitBucket* (or whatever system one uses) and the staging server, and production server.

#### Here's an example:

I am working on a site with the following structure (in part): (those with ++ around them are the folders I with files I must track/manage in GIT)
- `www_root/images/...`

- `www_root/etc/...`
- `www_root/extras/themes/...`
- `www_root/extras/plugins/...`
- ++ `www_root/extras/plugins/my-plugin-1` ++
- ++ `www_root/extras/plugins/my-plugin-2` ++
- ++ `www_root/extras/themes/my-theme-1` ++
- `www_root/extras/theme/someothertheme`

The approach I took on my *dev* server (localhost) was to have a repository for the entire `www_root/`, and a `gitignore` that excludes everything except those folders with the ++ next to them (in the above example), AND their parents. So in this case, the `../plugins/..` and `../themes/..` folders are both included in full.

When it comes time to set up the staging server, this is where I came unstuck. What I did was install the application on there (WordPress, in my present case). But then I can't add the GIT project, because I run into the issue that `git init` aborts due to the folder not being empty.

As mentioned, on my local server I'd set up the site root as the root of my project, and with `gitignore` all files except the various folders I am working in, are excluded.

## WHAT I TRIED

I attempted setting up a `project.git` folder above the web_root, and then adding a work-tree for the `/extras/` folder in the web root. I ran into issues. Could not `git init` (non-empty folders issue) and could not `git pull`, `git fetch`, etc.

I also attempted creating a GIT project within the www_root, and with the worktree being the `/extras/` folder, but again, struck the non-empty folder issue.

## QUESTIONS

1) Is there a way I can incorporate a GIT project, and pull down the files from Bitbucket/Github, into a an existing folder structure (such as would exist in any situation where one is developing components of a larger application, with its broader folder structure)?

2) OR, is it necessary to either have a completely empty `/wp-content/themes/` (in my example) folder on the staging and production server, and manage the entire content through GIT, and then GIT INIT and GIT CLONE into that folder, and then have a separate project for `/wp-content/plugins/` where all content of that folder is handled through GIT, etc., and do the same for that?

3) OR, is the best approach to have separate projects for each sub-folder? Hypothetically, `www_root/extras/themes/my-theme-1` and, let's say, `www_root/extras/themes/my-theme-2`, and perhaps `www_root/extras/plugins/my-plugin-1`

4) Or have I completely overlooked another way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an option, can you create a new folder, create a GIT repo in it and then move files into the repo?

Then the usual - in case of fire:

- git commit
- git push
- leave the building

Comment: Thanks. So what you're suggesting is this... Remove all content from `/wp-content` folder. Create the repo in it, which, in this particular case, will populate it with a `plugins` and `themes` folder, and some sub-folders in those. Then move back into the `/wp-config/` folder everything I took out (less whatever stuff GIT has put in there and is going to be handling). Correct?

Comment: Pretty much yes. GIT seems to have a problem creating a repo in a non-empty folder.